# getting results from promises. array or not

Tags: javascript

I just met some funny behavior reading response from a list of promises. When we have more than 1 promise, the results are array of promises results but when we have just one promise, the result is array of result `properties` which kinda throws everyone off the cliff.

Put in code:

```
var data = [/*...*/];
var requests = [];
for (var i in data) {
    // returns json(true or false)
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: '/push',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            item: data[i].item,
            other: dat[i].other
        }
    });

  requests.push(request);
}

$.when.apply(null, requests).done(function () {

    $.each(arguments, function (idx, result) {
        if (result.length > 0) {
            if (result[0]) {
                //
            }
        }
    });
});
```

when `data.length == 1`:

```
arguments = [false, "success", {readyState: 4, ...}, callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
```

when `data.length > 1`:

```
arguments = [Array(3), Array(3), callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
```

where for each promise `Array(3)` is:

```
[false (or true), "success", {readyState: 4, ...}, callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
```

why does JavaScript flattens the array for length == 1 or am i doing something wrong? That definitely breaks everything?

Comment: how about `$.when(requests).done(function(results){ /*...*/ })` instead of playing around with the optional arguments

Comment: and it's not Javascript that flattens anything, it's the intended/implemented behaviour in jQuery.

Comment: Yes, that's why you should not use jQuery but a proper promise library :-)